# Serverless: Serverless error property not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have this serverless.yaml

```
service: BATCH-lambda-f
provider:
  name: aws
  name: serverless-fac-${opt:stage,self:provider.stage}
runtime: nodejs12.x
stage: develop
custom:
   credentials: ${file(./scripts/myScript.js)}
```

in my myScript.js file I want to access the serverless functions in this way:

```
module.exports = async (serverless) => {
    serverless.cli.log('example');
    const stage = serverless.getProvider('aws').getStage();
    console.log(stage);
    .....
    .....
}
```

I get this error:

> Serverless Error
>
> ```
> Cannot resolve serverless.yaml: Variables resolution errored with:
> Cannot resolve variable at "custom.credentials": Cannot resolve "myScript.js": Returned JS function errored with: TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that `Cannot read property 'log' of undefined`
which means you are trying to access "cli" object from the "serverless" object passed to the function which does not exist basically. Try to cosole log serverless and check its value.